# What should be the preferred data type for primary key colum if in database(MSSQL) it is defined as Numeric(18,0)

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy

I am facing issues with defining table's primary key column as Numeric(18,0).I am connecting to a MSSQL and in database all tables are defined as Numeric(18,0) for primary key.
So to match with the database table schema I updated Sqlalchemy tables as Numeric(18,0) but I am facing Issues when the table is having an insert trigger.
Eg.

```
sometable = Table("sometable",
    metadata, 
    Column("sometable_id",Numeric(18,0), primary_key=True))
```

So I gone through the docs and found I need to turn of implicit_returning=False and optionally need to auto-increment primary_key so I changed my schema to bellow.

```
sometable = Table("sometable",
metadata, 
Column("sometable_id", Numeric(18,0), autoincrement=True,primary_key=True),
       implicit_returning=False)
```

But still it throws the bellow error
{FlushError: Instance  has a NULL identity key. If this is
an auto-generated value, check that the database table allows generation of new primary key
values, and that the mapped Column object is configured to expect these generated values.
Ensure also that this flush() is not occurring at an inappropriate time, such as within a load()
event.
}

After the issue I found that autoincrement is the problem I went ahead and changed my table schema to have data type BigInteger for primary key.

```
sometable = Table("sometable",
                   metadata, 
                   Column("sometable_id", BigInteger, autoincrement=True,primary_key=True),
                   implicit_returning=False)
```

And it worked fine for all cases including insert triggers as well.
So my question is what should be the preferred data type for primary keys in my scenario.
Do i continue using BigInteger.
Need suggestions guys.

Comment: The issue why `decimal` does not work can be related to the fact that `sqlalchemy` assumes only *Integer derived (INT, SMALLINT, BIGINT)* datatypes to support `autoincrement` feature. See [docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column.params.autoincrement) for more details. So keeping it with `BigInteger` just might do the trick.

Comment: I agree to use BigInt but its deviating from original table schema.I will ran into issues while creating the table with the schema.So I was expecting any suggestions or any other way of doing it.which might help to be in sync with DB.

Comment: Apart from being consistent with the rest of the database, if you do create new tables, I would advise to use `Integer` or `BigInteger` for the PK columns.

Comment: Thanks van that's better option in longer run.