# Forcing autoincrement on Numeric primary key with Sqlalchemy and SQL Server

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy, pymssql

I have an existing SQL Server (2012) DB with many tables having a primary key of `Numeric(9, 0)` type. For all intents and purposes they are integers.

The ORM mapping (generated using [sqlacodegen](https://bitbucket.org/agronholm/sqlacodegen/)) looks like:

```
class SomeTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'SOME_TABLE'
    __table_args__ = {'schema': 'dbo'}

    SOME_TABLE_ID = Column(Numeric(9, 0), primary_key=True)
    some_more_fields_here = XXX
```

Sample code to insert data:

```
some_table = SomeTable(_not_specifying_SOME_TABLE_ID_explicityly_)
session.add(some_table)
session.flush()    # <---BOOM, FlushError here
```

When I try to insert data into such tables, my app crashes on session.flush() with the following error:

> sqlalchemy.orm.exc.FlushError: Instance SomeTable ... has a NULL identity key.  If this is an auto-generated value, check that the database table allows generation of new primary key values, and that the mapped Column object is configured to expect these generated values.  Ensure also that this flush() is not occurring at an inappropriate time, such aswithin a load() event.

If I replace `Numeric` with `BigInteger` then everything works fine. I did some digging and the query generated with `Numeric` is like this:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.[SOME_TABLE] (_columns_without_SOME_TABLE_ID) 
    VALUES (...)
```

- seems like a valid query from SQL point of view, but Sqlalchemy raises the above exception there

The query generated using BigInteger is as follows:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.[SOME_TABLE] (_columns_without_SOME_TABLE_ID)
    OUTPUT inserted.[SOME_TABLE_ID] 
    VALUES (...)
```

I also found this [peace of documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_1/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column.params.autoincrement) about autoincrement property. And sure enough, it explains the behavior I observe, i.e. autoincrement only works with integers.
So my question is whether there is some kind of workaround to make `autoincrement` work with Numeric columns **without** converting them to `BigInteger`?

My system configuration is - Centos 7 64 bit, Python 3.5.2, Sqlalchemy 1.1.4, pymssql 2.2.0, SQL Server 2012.

Comment: Comments to a related question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28316177/2144390) seem to suggest "lying" to SQLAlchemy by telling it that the Identity column is integer-based. (After all, it is, "for all intents and purposes".)

Comment: I may end up having to do that. The problem is that my ORM mapping is auto-generated and every time I have to update it, I'll have to manually replace Numeric with BigInteger. Of course, I could automate that too, but it is starting to be a little too much hassle for something that "should just work".